# How much damage does fire do?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

How much damage does burning do over it's lifetime? Does it differ depending on class or the pyro's weapon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you mean Afterburn, which is the amount of fire damage you suffer after the flame thrower/flare's initial damage, assuming it is no longer directly hitting you:

Degreaser is 2 damage/half second for 10 seconds (40 total if not extinguished).  If a player is jarated, it does 3 damage/half second.

All other flamethrowers, flare guns, lit arrows, or the Cow Mangler 5000's charged shot are 3 damage/half second for 10 seconds (60 total if not extinguished).  If a player is jarated, it does 4 damage/half second.

Comment: I should note, I'm not sure how the Buff Banner affects Afterburn.

Comment: If the person who put you on fire is buffed w/ the Buff Banner, you will take minicrit damage until the effect ends.

Comment: How long is it before the pyro gets extinguished? Because it suffers less, but still some afterburn.

Comment: @RonanForman The Pyro takes direct fire damage (which is considerably higher than the damage mentioned here), but do not take afterburn damage.

Comment: @Ronan Forman: Just to clarify, the state of being "on fire" is a different mechanic from afterburn. A Pyro can be briefly set on fire, during which time he can be extinguished or suffer a critical hit from a flare or the Axtinguisher, but he can never take afterburn damage.